# Couple questions about using Rsync?

Tags: rsync

I can't find any reliable file syncing program for my Mac, so I have been using the command line Rsync between two folders.

I have been using "rsync -r source destination".

-Does this sync files both ways, or only sync the source to the destination?
-If a file was previously synced between the two folders, but deleted because it is no longer needed, does it get deleted on both the source and destination, or will it just always get copied to where it is missing from?

Answer (score 4):

No, `rsync` will synchronise the contents of a remote directory to a local directory.  In that respect it is one-way.  Optionally you can force it to delete local files that no longer exist in the remote folder.

If you want to keep the most recent changes on both machines, you would have to supply a more complicated rsync incantation and set up both machines as rsync servers.  I imagine doing so will get you into trouble eventually, especially if you want to be authoritarian over deletion.

In any case, you can use the `-u` (or `--update`) option which will skip any files that are newer on the destination end.  You do have to worry about the timestamps, and this will not handle any conflicts or merges.  Still...  It may be as simple as:

```
rsync -u -r target1 target2
rsync -u -r target2 target1
```

That won't do anything about deletion.  You have no way of knowing that a missing file on one target was deleted there instead of a new file having been created on the other target.

This is why version control was invented...  And for people who are scared of version control, services like DropBox exist.

Answer (score 1):

Answering original question :

1)It synchronizes files only in one direction depending on pull or push mechanism .
  for push and pull mechanism , see manual page by ""man rsync"".

*so, for the rest of your question don't assume that it works in both
 ways.*

2)The file only gets deleted on destination directory.
get more details on this in `rsync --help` command ,see option 
--delete which delete extraneous files from destination dirs
and others options for delete.

3) The missing files will be copied just to destination directory if you are **pushing** files on remote machine/directory/

a sample example for push mechanism :-

```
rsync -avz /home/local_dir/abc.txt remoteuser@192.168.xx.xx:/home/remoteuser/
```

if a file named abc.txt is already present in destination directory then it will be updated depending upon it is old version of abc.txt on local side or not.
And if abc.txt is not present on remote directory , a total new file named abc.txt will be created with contents of local version of abc.txt

a sample example for pull mechanism :-

```
rsync -avz remoteuser@192.168.xx.xx:/home/remoteuser/abc.txt /home/local_dir/
```

if a file named abc.txt is already present in local directory then it will be updated depending upon it is old version of abc.txt on remote side or not.
And if abc.txt is not present on local directory , a total new file named abc.txt will be created with contents of local version of abc.txt